# LaTeX code for text above the $\rightarrow$

Tags: math-mode, symbols, relation-symbols

Hi I am wondering what code is used to get text above the `$\rightarrow$`

have tried `$ \xrightarrow{P}$` but not running on my LaTeX as I do not know which package to install or how to install it.

currently using `\usepackage{mathtools}` but it wants to load from a random directory and then LaTeX stops working.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [quant.se]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) should be part of every distribution out there. I would suggest following the instructions in [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://goo.gl/CqWB1) to make sure you have a compatible and complete distribution, which should make even the most minimal of documents (`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$ \xrightarrow{P}$
\end{document}`) compile.

Answer (score 9):

`\xrightarrow` is provided by package `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\xrightarrow{P}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

LaTeX package `amsmath` is part of distribution package `amsmath` in TeX Live
 and MiKTeX. Usually it should be already installed, because it belongs to the "required" packages: `CTAN:macros/latex/required/amslatex/`.

Package `mathtools` loads package `amsmath` and provides further extensible arrows, see section "3.3 Extensible symbols" in its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mh/mathtools.pdf).
It is part of distribution package `mh` in MiKTeX and TeX Live.